# error de falta un parentesis a la derecha ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola soy novato en codigo sql y me piden que cree unas tablas con sql. Al crear la tabla me da el error de falta un parentesis a la derecha ORA-00907 y no encuentro la causa.

Esta es la estructura que yo he creado.

```
create table ALUMNOS(
nombre_id varchar2 (30),
apellido1 varchar2 (30),
apellido2 varchar2 (30),
nif varchar (10),
direccion varchar2 (100),
sexo varchar (10),
f_nac date (20),
cur_mat number (10),
primary key (nombre_id));
```

gracias por la ayuda y un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo siento que el mensaje de error no sea muy útil en este caso.

El error es que no le debes especificar una longitud al tipo `DATE`. Si le quitas el `(20)`, la sentencia funcionará:

```
create table ALUMNOS(
nombre_id varchar2 (30),
apellido1 varchar2 (30),
apellido2 varchar2 (30),
nif varchar (10),
direccion varchar2 (100),
sexo varchar (10),
f_nac date, -- quita el (20) aquí
cur_mat number (10),
primary key (nombre_id));
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias quitado y resuelto.

Comment: @chobi si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, por favor, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el icono que aparece en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa lo mismo con el tipo **TIMESTAMP**.

El manejador de Oracle y Generador de DLL te los autogenera de esta forma

```
FECHA_INI_GESTION TIMESTAMP(6)(0),  <---- (6)(0)
```

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE (<br>
    ID_TRANSACCION VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,<br>
    CONSUMIDOR VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,<br>
    PLATAFORMA_DESTINO VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,<br>
    PARM_ENTRADA CLOB,<br>
    PARM_SALIDA CLOB,<br>
    FECHA_INI_GESTION TIMESTAMP(6)(0), </h3><br>
    FECHA_FIN_GESTION TIMESTAMP(6)(0), </h3><br>
    TIPO_EJECUCION VARCHAR2(30),<br>
    CODIGO_RESP VARCHAR2(10)<br>
);
```

---

Para la Creacion te acepta la siguiente declaracion de tipo:

```
FECHA_INI_GESTION TIMESTAMP,
```

o

```
FECHA_INI_GESTION TIMESTAMP(6),<br>
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE (
    ID_TRANSACCION VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSUMIDOR VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PLATAFORMA_DESTINO VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PARM_ENTRADA CLOB,
    PARM_SALIDA CLOB,
    FECHA_INI_GESTION TIMESTAMP,
    FECHA_FIN_GESTION TIMESTAMP(6),
    TIPO_EJECUCION VARCHAR2(30),
    CODIGO_RESP VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me piden crear unas tablas con sql. Al crear la tabla me da el error de falta un paréntesis a la derecha `ORA-00907` y no encuentro la causa.
Esta es la estructura que yo he creado.

```
create table visitas (
  numero int identity,
  nombre varchar(30) default 'Anonimo',
  mail varchar(50),
  pais varchar (20),
  fecha date,
  primary key(numero)
);
```

no encuentro cual es la casa

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/314832)